# Best way to create entity objects with default properties

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Post entity in my Blog bundle.  Posts can have many comments.  When I create a new comment entity to attach to a post I have to set a bunch of properties such as,

```
$comment->setTimestamp( new \DateTime() );
$comment->setUserId( $this->getUser()->getId() );
$comment->setHost( $this->getClientIP() );
```

default timezone is easy in the constructor of the entity.  How do I automatically set the userid and clientip when constructing the entity?  getClientIP is a function in the controller at the moment.  This should be service.  Can I have a factory that creates comments for me?

Comment: Btw, for that timestamp... take a look at the Gedmo bundle (https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions). It has the following: Timestampable - updates date fields on create, update and even property change.

Comment: I take it you are not using Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your best bet would be a `class CommentFactory extends EntityFactory`.

The factory would be responsible for creating your Entities for you, you pass the required entities (Such as the user entity) and it would return new objects for you:

```
$commentFactory = new CommentFactory($user, $client, $whatever);
$comment = $commentFactory->getNewComment();
```

Comment: This is what im thinking too. Where is the EntityFactory class?  I can't find it in the API.

Comment: It doesn't exist , you need to make it :). It should be an abstract class, with undefined methods that make sense in  a factory context (`create()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can call any entity method from an entity construct, and you can pass anything from controller to a new instance of the comment.
For instance, get timestamp, userid and host in controller action, and pass those as parameters to a construct of Comment entity. 
Make calls to setter methods in a construct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Comment probably isnt a great example as this would be handled by one controller.  If I wanted to add comments to posts from many controllers I need a factory for creating comments with defaults like user and ip.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper function in controller for that

```
protected function getNewComment() {
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setTimestamp( new \DateTime() );
    $comment->setUserId( $this->getUser()->getId() );
    $comment->setHost( $this->getClientIP() );

    return $comment;
}
```

And then

```
$comment = $this->getNewComment();
```

Comment: True, can i move this to a service.  Say comment as actually a note object and could be attached to other entities?  So I would have a note service or factory I could call that would set defaultS?

Comment: Of course if you can get all dependencies. You can pass `security` to service and get current user, but I dont know that is `$this->getClientIP()`. If you can extract IP from `request` then service which acts as a factory is a good idea.

Comment: I was going to put getIP() out into a Client service also.

Comment: You can pass Client service as argument to your service and create fresh comment